# ajax post formData empty for one user, windows 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I  have this code that has been working for a while, but one of my users recently had their account upgraded to windows 11 and now it is posting empty data. Not sure if windows 11 is the cause or if a setting got adjusted, but it works for all other users so I'm confused on what to do about it.

```
    // Iterate through the selected files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        // Create a FormData object for the current file
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('postedFiles', file); // 'uploadedFile' should match the parameter name in the controller action


        // Use AJAX to send the file to the server 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/UploadFile', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle the response, e.g., show success message
                var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
                newWindow.document.write(response);
                if (i >= files.length) { formbody.classList.remove('hidden'); formspinner.classList.add('hidden'); closeValidatorModal(); }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle the error, e.g., show error message
                alert("Invalid file, please use xfiles only and only xfiles generated from this tool.");
                if (i >= files.length) { formbody.classList.remove('hidden'); formspinner.classList.add('hidden'); closeValidatorModal(); }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "it doesn't work for them" - what does that mean?

Comment: It's posting empty data for them only.
Sorry, didn't explain that clearly; fixed original post.

Comment: How do you see the empty data? have you seen the user's network tab? or your API is receiving an empty request?

Comment: It's erroring out at the viewresult, '''public ViewResult UploadFile(List<IFormFile> postedFiles)''' I have code that loops through postedFiles, but when it goes to try to initiate the loop, it says that postedFiles is empty.